# how to select age of people who fit the condition with now() date

Tags: php

```
$query="select * from person_details (datediff(now(),dob))/365>25";
```

The output is:

> Can't Execute Query...

Comment: You don't have any `WHERE` statement..

Comment: `Can't Execute Query` sounds like a custom error message. You should add more code, and use error reporting. Additionally please use the tags correctly, this has nothing to do with HTML.

Comment: Also you may want to add a tag indicating what database you are using: mysql, sqlite, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to get the people who are older than 25, am I correct?

If so, the correct way to implement it is

```
$age_required = 25;
$query="SELECT * FROM person_details 
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, dob, GetDate()) > ".$age_required;
```

Hope it helped.